# containsLocation() Polyline in Polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a possibilty to check that Polyline is in Polygon? Or I must check each points in Polyline containsLocation in Polygon?
I think about importing gpx files (my Polyline) and check what administrative area (my Polygons) contains this Polyline. I was thinking about reverse geocoding for each points in Polyline, but its impossible due to geocoding limitations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check every point of the Polyline against your Polygon. Take into account that a Polyline can be (according to [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM)):

- Within your polygon (contained) = completely contained
- Intersect your polygon = partially contained
- Disjoint = not contained

So, a polyline can intersect two different Polygons (your Polyline can intersect two different administrative areas)

Comment: Which way is better? containsLocation from GoogleMaps Api or ST_Intersect from MySQL? I have Polygons and Polygons with many points...

Comment: It depends, because `containsLocation` executes client side and `st_intersects` executes server side